# HTML Form and PHP Script not working

Tags: php, html, forms, button

I have created a form in HTML and a processing script in PHP. When I hit the send button, nothing happens.

My HTML Form:

```
            <form method="post" action="../core/code/php/notes.php" id="sendNote">
            <input type="hidden" name="sender" value="user">
            <ol>
            <li><label for="sendto">Send to:</label></li>
            <li>
                <select name="sendto">
                    <option value="admin">admin</option>
                    <option value="bnguyen654">bnguyen654</option>
               </select>  
            </li>
            <li><label for="message">Message:</label></li>
            <li><textarea name="message" style="font-family:'Charter BT';"></textarea></li>
            <li><input type="button" value="Send" name="send"></li>
            </ol>             
            </form>
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php 
$to = $_REQUEST['sendto']; 
$from = $_REQUEST['sender'] ; 
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

if($message == '') {echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("You have not entered a message, please go back and try again"); history.go(-1)</script>';} 
else { 
$file = "../../../Admin/%to/notes.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("Can't find file");
$stringData = "%message ~%from";
$send = fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh); 

if($send)
    {echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Message sent successfully"); window.location={"../../../Admin"};</script>';} 
else {
{echo "We encountered an error sending your message, please try again."; } 
}
}

?>
```

The send button does nothing. No success message or error. This is really frustrating. I do tend to overlook things thought so...

- This is on a server
- The links are correct
- I know it's a lot to go through
- Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
~BN

Answer (score 3):

There are two errors that I can see:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sender" value="login">
                                         ^ Needs quotes around the value
```

and

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
              ^ Change this to Submit from send.
```

In HTML there is no form input with a type of "send", the `submit` type however submits the form when pressed.

Edit (As per comment below):

If you aren't getting into the part of the script that is echo'ing out some javascript, it is because you aren't writing to the file. I have checked the echo statement, and it works perfectly well. This means that either you aren't able to write to the file - `fwrite()` returns a false if it hasn't written to the file. Also, if it cannot open it properly - ie, `fopen()` failed, then it will also return a false.

Looking at your code some more, you name the file you want to update `$file` but then refer to it as `$myFile` in the `fopen()` command.

```
$file = "../../../Admin/%to/notes.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("Can't find file");
```

You should probably be using the same variable eh?

```
$myFile = "../../../Admin/%to/notes.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("Can't find file");
```

Edit 2: To test a connection after an `fopen()` you can do the following:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("Can't find file");
if($fh)
{ echo "Connection to file is okay";}
else { echo "File couldn't be opened it seems.";}
```

It is basically the same thing you are doing with your `$send` variable right to the end of your published code.

Comment: It's successful but for some reason the _alert box_ doesn't pop up.

Comment: @BrandonNguyen Made an edit to the answer, while I am happy to help, be sure to carefully step through your code - you should be able to find mismatched variables yourself - though I do get that sometimes we simply miss them.

Comment: @BrandonNguyen Okay, can you pass some extra information? Is it writing to the file? Can you test to see whether `$fh` returns true after the `fwrite()`? Need some extra information, rather than "doesn't work" mate :)

Comment: Um.. I'm sort of a beginner so how would you do that?

Comment: @BrandonNguyen I made another edit. Can you have a play with that one and try to track down where the error is happening?

Comment: Connection to file is okay.

Comment: @BrandonNguyen Is it writing to the file?

Comment: Can you now add in a `print_r($send);` just after the `$send = fwrite($fh, $stringData);` line and see what happens?

Comment: I put in _Test_ and it returned _12_.

Comment: OK. I fixed it. The mistake was in the `window.location`. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong input type. The button input type is used for an actionless button that you can attach javascript to. The submit type is for submitting a form.

Comment: Is your script tag with the alert call actually getting echoed?

Comment: Did you call var_dump($send) to see exactly what is happening as a result of your fwrite call?